# Removing the default native control bar in HTML5

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I am wondering how can I remove a default native control bar, which is being showed behind my own.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the [`controls`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) attribute from the markup.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *default* native control bar. The native control bar is only displayed if you explicitly turn it on (normally by adding a `controls` attribute to the video start tag, but you may have turned it on using JS instead).

Remove the attribute or the JS that sets the `controls` property to `true`.